# How to use loop in SSRS

Tags: loops, reporting-services

In SQL Server, a simple loop statement as shown below works fine

while @loopCount < 10
begin
select 'loop counter = ', @loopCount
set @loopCount= @loopCount + 1
end

But, I can't seem to make this work in the reporting services, it asked that the @loopCount needs to be declared, but if its declared it would only show the top 1 result instead of 10 rows.

I believe it can be done through a stored procedure, but I am avoiding to use that.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to loop in a report? Maybe if we knew what you were trying to accomplish we could steer you in the right direction.

Comment: A SSRS SQL dataset will only use the first result set returned. If you need to combine datasets, then use the SQL `UNION ALL` operation

Answer (score 0):

If your report is accessing a SQLServer data source, the simplest way to return the top 10 results is simply to add `top 10` to the select clause, so that it becomes `select top 10 ...`. Many other versions of SQL have similar options.

Alternatively, you can set up Top 10 filtering in the Tablix Properties dialog, in the Filters section - the dropdown box for Operator should include Top N as an option, and you can specify 10 as the value to be filtered.